# How to fix if the react native android build is failed?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am very new to React native app developer. Please help me to fix the below issue
I am facing the below issues while executing react-native run-android.

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1112 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
92 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 88 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Unable to delete directory 'E:\React Native\RNProjects\AHHCSTAFF\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx\appcompat' after 10 attempts
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Unable to delete directory 'E:\React Native\RNProjects\AHHCSTAFF\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx\appcompat' after 10 attempts
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s

```
at makeError (E:\React Native\RNProjects\AHHCSTAFF\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at E:\React Native\RNProjects\AHHCSTAFF\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (E:\React Native\RNProjects\AHHCSTAFF\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (E:\React Native\RNProjects\AHHCSTAFF\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

I dont know how to fix all the above issues

Answer (score -1):

I have met this error logs before. Here are my resolve steps:(executing in progect root dictory)

```
cd android 
gradlew clean
```

And run `yarn android`,it works well.By the way,my RN version is 0.62. You can have a try.